# Left Join query in MySQL returning null rows for all results

Tags: mysql

I'm having an odd problem with a left join query:
Table 1: **Rates**

```
Serial, peopleSerial, jobSerial
1, 23, 1
1, 24, 1
1, 25, 1
1, 26, 1
```

Table 2: **People**

```
Serial, otherKey, name1, address, etc...
23, 65, John, street, etc...
24, 66, Mike, street, etc...
25, 67, Alex, street, etc...
```

This should be fairly simple to left join the data from the PEOPLE table.
Here's the query I'm using:

```
SELECT rates.*, people.* FROM rates
LEFT JOIN people ON people.Serial = Rates.peopleSerial
```

I would expect to see a result like this:
**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
Serial, peopleSerial, jobSerial, Serial, otherKey, name1, address, etc...
1, 23, 1, 23, 65, John, Street, etc...
2, 24, 1, 24, 66, Mike, Street, etc...
3, 25, 1, 25, 67, Alex, Street, etc...
4, 26, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, etc...
```

But instead this is the result I actually get:
**ACTUAL RESULT**

```
Serial, peopleSerial, jobSerial, Serial, otherKey, name1, address, etc...<br>
1, 23, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, etc...
2, 24, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, etc...
3, 25, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, etc...
4, 26, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, etc...
```

**EDIT**:
Here's a data dump and SQL fiddle of same, which is returning the same result. Above example was a simplified version of this. I have cleared most of the subcon_people_dev table as it is confidential information, but some populated fields should still appear:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subcon_rates` (
  `serial` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subcon_serial` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_serial` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_serial` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chargeRate` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `period` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`serial`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=999 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `subcon_rates` (`serial`, `subcon_serial`, `job_serial`, `type_serial`, `rate`, `chargeRate`, `period`) VALUES
    (134, 52, 27, 1, 10.00, 15.00, '2018-10-14'),
    (138, 56, 27, 1, 25.00, 30.00, '2018-10-14'),
    (136, 55, 27, 1, 20.00, 25.00, '2018-10-14'),
    (139, 54, 27, 1, 35.00, 40.00, '2018-10-14'),
    (140, 52, 27, 1, 10.00, 15.00, '2018-10-07'),
    (141, 56, 27, 1, 25.00, 30.00, '2018-10-07'),
    (142, 55, 27, 1, 20.00, 25.00, '2018-10-07'),
    (143, 54, 27, 1, 35.00, 40.00, '2018-10-07'),
    (153, 54, 27, 1, 10.00, 15.00, '2018-10-21'),
    (152, 55, 27, 1, 10.00, 15.00, '2018-10-21'),
    (866, 52, 27, 1, 10.00, 15.00, '2018-10-21'),
    (150, 52, 27, 1, 10.00, 15.00, '2018-10-21');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subcon_people_dev` (
  `serial` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subconNumber` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` text,
  `title` text,
  `name1` text,
  `surname` text,
  `nino` text,
  `ref` text,
  `tradingname` text,
  `crn` text,
  `pName` text,
  `pUTR` text,
  `add1` text,
  `add2` text,
  `add3` text,
  `add4` text,
  `postcode` text,
  `UTR` text,
  `role` text,
  `company` text,
  `insuranceExpire` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `approved` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sortCode` text,
  `accountNumber` text,
  `accountName` text,
  `placcount` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`serial`),
  UNIQUE KEY `subconNumber` (`subconNumber`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=69 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `subcon_people_dev` (`serial`, `subconNumber`, `type`, `title`, `name1`, `surname`, `nino`, `ref`, `tradingname`, `crn`, `pName`, `pUTR`, `add1`, `add2`, `add3`, `add4`, `postcode`, `UTR`, `role`, `company`, `insuranceExpire`, `approved`, `sortCode`, `accountNumber`, `accountName`, `placcount`) VALUES
    (1, '0001', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (2, '0010', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (3, '0011', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (4, '0012', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (5, '0013', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (6, '0014', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (7, '0015', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (8, '0016', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (9, '0017', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (10, '0018', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (11, '0019', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (12, '0002', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (13, '0020', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (14, '0021', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (15, '0022', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (16, '0023', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (17, '0024', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (18, '0025', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (19, '0026', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (20, '0027', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (21, '0028', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (22, '0029', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (23, '0003', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (24, '0030', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (25, '0031', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (26, '0032', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (27, '0033', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (28, '0034', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (29, '0035', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (30, '0036', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (31, '0037', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (32, '0038', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (33, '0039', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (34, '0004', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (35, '0040', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (36, '0041', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (37, '0042', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (38, '0043', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (39, '0044', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (40, '0045', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (41, '0046', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (42, '0047', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (43, '0048', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (44, '0049', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (45, '0005', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (46, '0050', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (47, '0051', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (48, '0052', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (49, '0006', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (50, '0007', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (51, '0008', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (59, '62', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (60, '54', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (61, '55', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (62, '59', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (63, '53', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (64, '58', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (65, '56', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (66, '60', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (67, '0061', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', '', '', ''),
    (68, '0063', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', '', '', '');
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uBWYs5UvZy62fJiWJHpwPD/1

Comment: I find it hard to believe that left join caused that result.. see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tbxMSPi5zArhshEFVnyA3Q/0 .. So i think a IDE cache or application code is the problem here???

Comment: Please create a SQL fiddle / DB Fiddle so that we can verify your claim.

Comment: Can you share the DDLs for the tables? Perhaps it's some implicit casting issue?

Comment: You are selecting from only one table rates... I think the query should be SELECT rates.*, people.* FROM rates, people
LEFT JOIN people ON people.Serial = Rates.peopleSerial

Comment: in short no @DPS `FROM rates, people ` without matching where is a cross join..

Comment: @DPS there is a `LEFT JOIN people ON` for that. In the meantime i tested everything i could, but i can't replicate user's result.

Comment: Just setting up a SQL Fiddle / DB Fiddle now.

Comment: @DPS Besides you shouldn't be mixing the old comma join syntax with the newer join syntax it's asking for trouble

Comment: @DPS Forget about mixing. You should not even use comma join syntax EVER!

Comment: "You should not even use comma join syntax EVER!" @MadhurBhaiya well comma join syntax is over 25 years old but i believe still not marked for deprecation by ANSI SQL  standards (still hoping for this).. But sure the comma join is less readable, flexible and portable vs the more modern join syntax https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/comma-vs-join/

Comment: SQL Fiddle added to the post above.

Comment: @RaymondNijland there are lots of things in Programming languages which dont get deprecated, just for the sake of backward compatability. I am pretty sure that a large substantial number of websites are still running on versions older than PHP5; because they are working just fine; but any new development should preferably be done in better and safer ways

Comment: @Sam Please check your fiddle clearly; there are no matching rows for `subcon_serial` = 52, 54, 55, 56 in other tabe. That is why you are getting all `null`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Well I feel stupid now, must have been deleted somewhere along the line. Sorry to waste your time, thank you!

Comment: I've voted to close this question

Answer (score 1):

You got nulls because you don't have any matching keys... In subcon_people_dev you don't have rows with subcon_serial (52, 54, 55, 56).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Join order. In case of `Left Join`, leftmost table should be the one, from which you want to consider all the rows (whether having a matching row in other tables or not).

```
select subcon_rates.*, subcon_people_dev.* 
from subcon_people_dev
left join subcon_rates on subcon_people_dev.`serial` = subcon_rates.subcon_serial
```